# nginx rewrite not working - returning 404

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I'm trying to rewrite :

http://example/test/  -> http://example/new/

http://example/test/check -> http://example/new/check

```
location ~/test/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/new/$1?$args permanent;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `rewrite  ^ http://example$request_uri? permanent;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rewrite` statement is incorrect. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

To use `rewrite` to capture the latter part of the URI, try:

```
rewrite ^/test/(.*)$ /new/$1 permanent;
```

Alternatively, to use `location` to capture the latter part of the URI, try:

```
location ~ ^/test/(.*)$ {
    return 301 /new/$1?$args;
}
```